# how to dynamically build a tree structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## In my view, I get all pages

I get all my pages and also all the children and sub-children. How to get the tree structure as shown below:

```
<% for page in @pages%>
<li id="<%= page.id%>_page">    
    <div class="link">    
        #my attributes for the div<
      /div>    
#here I got the all siblings of that page. But here the structure is of just two      
#levels. I need upto n-levels.    
<% @childs = page.*descendants* %>    
<% if !@childs.nil? && !@childs.empty? %>
    <% for child in @childs%>     
    <ol class="child">
        <li id="<%= child.id%>_page">
            <div class="link">
                #my attributes for the div
            </div>
            </li>
    </ol>
    <%end%>
    <%end%>
</li>
<%end%>
```

## I am using nested set and want the structure in this way:

```
page1
     page 2
     page 3
           page 3.1
                   page 3.2
                           page3.4
                                   ...so on to last child
page 4
page 5
....so on to N-levels...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create recursion inside a view, which not only is complicated and will clutter your view code to much.
A clean way would be to define a helper function that generates the output recursively.

I don't have any concrete examples, but you can check one at one of the answers of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074607/why-does-my-recursive-method-from-helper-not-return-every-value)

Comment: after trying ..i got the solution...i render the partial which in turn render itself..such as

Answer (score 0):

after trying ..i got the
     solution...i render the partial which in turn render itself..such as _show_children.html.erb
    ..

```
    <% for page in @pages%>
    <li id="<%= page.id%>_page">    
        <div class="link">    
            #my attributes for the div<
          /div>    
    #here I got the all siblings of that page. But here the structure is of just two      
    #levels. I need upto n-levels.    
    <% @childs = page.descendants %>    
    <% if !@childs.nil? && !@childs.empty? %>
        <% for child in @childs%>     
         <%= render :partial => "show_children", :locals  => {:children => child`enter code here`.children  }%>
        <%end%>
        <%end%>
    </li>
<%end%>


.this partial will inturn render itself`
```