# why can't get my recursive method to only tree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, liquid, helper

My question is that, same [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074607/why-does-my-recursive-method-from-helper-not-return-every-value) . But I want to show tree structure not all of values, only tree structure.

When we write, below method, displaying all values with details. 
[you can show output of below function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpGtF.png)

`module CategoriesHelper
    def display_tree(category)
     tree = category.name 
     if category.has_children? 
       category.children.each do |sub_category|
         tree += "/#{display_tree(sub_category)}"
       end
    end
    tree
   end
 end`

But I want to show only tree structure [you can see what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aeIz.png).

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand what seems to be the issue. Could you clarify a bit: a) what you have now b) what is wrong with it and c) what have you tried to fix the issue?

Comment: Looking at the images, I'd conclude that you've achieved your goal.